# Select Command & Join Issue

Tags: php, select, join, authentication

I have two Tables

`1: USERS`

`user_id |
user_state | 
user_email`

`2: CONTACTS`

`contact_id |
contact_name |
contact_state |
contact_email |
contact_info`

What I want to do is for the select to echo all "CONTACTS" data where the "user_state" (which is the logged in users state) is equal to contact_state.

```
"SELECT * FROM contacts
INNER JOIN users
ON contact_state = ".$row_userinfo['user_state']."
WHERE contact_state = ".$row_userinfo["user_state"]." 
ORDER BY contact_name $limit");
?>
```

What I'm having trouble with is its not only showing the data that matches the logged in users state (user_state)

and with the above code (which I'm not to sure if it is correct to work the way I want) is coming up with "Unknown column '...' in 'where clause'"

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: Check `ON` clause, u have to specify `field name` from db table

Comment: dont pass parameters directly to the query, it makes it vulnerable to sql injections. read the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)..

Answer (score 1):

Try this query..

```
("SELECT contacts.*
FROM users, contacts
WHERE users.user_state = contacts.contact_state AND user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
```

here `$_SESSION['id']` is your current users login ID.

Comment: This one I thought would be the best option, but it wont bring any results back. Not sure why though. Just going over my session values and checking if I have missed something.

Comment: @Rocsha yes, you need to check the session id and then pass it to the query

Comment: what do you mean "pass it to the query"?

Comment: your session id.. pass it to query means, just change my variable `$_SESSION['id']` to yours `user_id = session_id`

Answer (score 0):

check the condition in `JOIN` Clause

```
("SELECT * FROM contacts
INNER JOIN users ON contact_state = user_state
WHERE contact_state = ".$row_userinfo["user_state"]." 
ORDER BY contact_name $limit");
```

Answer (score 0):

just change you ON clauses to

```
SELECT * FROM `users` a
JOIN `contacts` b
ON a.`user_state` = b.`contact_state`
WHERE a.`user_state` = '".$row_userinfo["user_state"]."' 
ORDER BY b.`contact_name` $limit"
```

this is because you are comparing two tables and need to declare what fields of two table are chosen for comparing

**note** you are not indicating whatever you want to order by `ASC` or `DESC` so i assume you already stored this in `$limit` variable

Comment: This answer is simular to one I came up with but as the same with my one it kept echoing the results twice. I did some tests and figured out that if I change the state of other users it echos the results the same amount of times and there are that many users. IE: one user has one state, echos results once, three users have the same state echos the results three times.

Comment: This is because you need to do in the opposite way,let me fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"SELECT c.* FROM contacts c
 JOIN users u
ON c.contact_state = u.user_state
WHERE c.contact_state = ".$row_userinfo["user_state"]." 
ORDER BY c.contact_name $limit"
```